# How to pass methods in Jenkins Groovy?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

Below is the Jenkins groovy code in scripted pipeline, we use to pass methods

```
def dict = [:]
def register(String x, Closure y){ dict[x]=y }
```

we say `register('a', this.&foo)` to pass a method to `register()` accepting closures as second argument

where `foo()` is a method

```
def foo(parm){
   // do something with parm
}
```

where `parm`'s possible value is 'a'

---

What should be the type of second argument of `register` method to avoid passing `this.&foo` and rather invoke `register('a', foo)`?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to invoke `register('a', foo)` then `foo` has to be a closure like e.g.

```
def foo = {
    // closure body here
}
```

instead of

```
def foo() {
    // method body here
}
```

The construction `this.&foo` is called [method pointer operator](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/core-operators.html#method-pointer-operator) and it is used to transform a method to a closure. If `foo` has to remain a method then you can't avoid `this.&foo` operator. Groovy does not support passing methods as `foo`. On the other hand, your `register` method expects a closure as a second parameter, so have to options:

- define `foo` as a closure
- or transform `foo` method to a closure with `this.&foo` operator

Comment: how to invoke a specific closure? this syntax does not work `dict['a']('a')`. In our scenario it is `def variable = 'a'` and we want to do `dict[var](var)`

Comment: actually it is `def foo(parm){}` method in the query. Query edited

Comment: Am expecting second parameter of `register` to receive method type but not closure type

Comment: @overexchange Groovy does not support passing methods as parameters to functions. That is why the method pointer parameter was introduced because closure in Groovy is an equivalent of a method (in simplification of course).

Comment: ok if I have method `def foo(parm){}`, then I will pass `register('a', this.&foo)`. But how do I invoke `foo` using `dict`?

Comment: @overexchange Maybe you are missing `@Field` annotation over `dict` variable and it is out of the `register` method scope. Take a look at this example: https://gist.github.com/wololock/b0c06a8a8aac17d9015b13142c640839

Comment: You mess up with scopes. `pushMethodLookUp` should be outside the `node`, otherwise it is a local variable of the `Push` stage and the `register` method has no chance to access it. Start with moving `pushMethodLookUp` outside of the node. You will need `@Field` annotation as well most probably, so `register` method access an object level variable.

Comment: Yes I moved outside node. But why should I require @Field annotation? I have other variable s inside node and outside stages, without Field annotation and they wotk fine. Code is in gist

Comment: Every Groovy script compiles to a class that extends `groovy.lang.Script`. The body of the script is moved to a `Script.run()` method, so every variable used in the script is a local variable of `Script.run()` method. The `@Field` annotation promotes variable to be a class field instead of a local variable. Every method defined in the script is compiled as a class method, e.g. `register()` method is `Script.register()` method. In this method you try to access `pushMethodLookUp`, so if you want to share it between `register` method and node body, you need to promote it to a class field.

Answer (score 0):

Function reference can be obtained using the "&" character; e.q this.&bar

```
def foo(Closure c) {
   c("foo")
 }

def bar(arg) {
    println "Hellow World: ${arg}"
 }
 
 println(foo(this.&bar))

 Output:
     Hellow World: foo
```